# C++ functions can be called from the console app, but not from the MAUI app

Tags: c#, c++, maui

I want to call a function written in C++ in my MAUI project.
I have written a program that calls a simple function as follows

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

# set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc" CACHE string "gcc compiler" FORCE)
# set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++" CACHE string "g++ compiler" FORCE)

project(hoge)

add_library(hoge SHARED hoge.cpp)

target_include_directories(hoge PRIVATE .)

add_executable(a.out main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(a.out hoge)
```

`hoge.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>


extern "C" {
  const char* return_hoge();
  int inc(int i);
}
```

`hoge.cpp`

```cpp
#include "hoge.h"

const char* return_hoge() {
  return "hoge";
}

int inc(int i){
  return i + 1;
}
```

And the C# code is as follows
`MainPage.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CallCppFunction.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label x:Name="Hoge"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

`MainPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
namespace CallCppFunction;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // DLL Import


public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                // count++;
        count = Inc(count);

                if (count == 1)
                        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
                else
                        CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

                SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        IntPtr ptr = ReturnHoge();
        string stg = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
        Hoge.Text = stg;
        }

    [DllImport("./thirdparty/libhoge.dylib", EntryPoint="return_hoge")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReturnHoge();

    [DllImport("./thirdparty/libhoge.dylib", EntryPoint="inc")]
    public static extern int Inc(int i);

}
```

When I run this code, it compiles fine, but does not run.

I have created a C# console application with the C++ code. The following code worked fine, and I used exactly the same as above regarding the C++ libraries.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IntPtr ptr = ReturnHoge();
        string str = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

    [DllImport("./thirdparty/libhoge.dylib", EntryPoint="return_hoge")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReturnHoge();
}
```

I would like to know how to use C++ functions in a MAUI project.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) to consume a native library, P/Invoke is a technology that allows you to access structs, callbacks, and functions in unmanaged libraries from your managed code. What needs to be said is that Maui is evolved from Xamarin.Forms, you could try to check this doc - [Use C/C++ libraries with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/), then try to adjust to implement a version of MAUI.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer.　I am asking how to adapt to the MAUI version.

Comment: Maui is evolved from Xamarin.Forms, you can refer to the Xamarin documentation in the answer to implement it in Maui.